# How to make a customed datepicker with selectable input? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I have a simple problem in regards of changing `input` value. When I type a char the value was displayed, but my problem is the cursor stopped. This is the [npm datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) that I used by the way.

Can someone help me fix?

[Play this demo video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-nHRXB8dlt-VyeaRG2lUEvfEvfIc5X21/view?usp=sharing)

Goal: is to create customed design input, that can change the date using datepicker and changing the directly to input.

---

Here is my code:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

const InputDate = () => {
  const ExampleCustomInput = forwardRef(({ value, onClick }, ref) => (
    <button>
        <input
            type='text'
            onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
            value={date}
        />
    </button>
  ));
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        selected={date}
        customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: First thing, you can't put an Input (ie. [Interactive Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content)) inside a Button: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Not an answer because I haven't tested, but I suspect that React and the browser is getting confused which element should have focus because both the `button` and `input` are focusable and combining them is invalid html

Comment: @FredStark i tested using `div` instead of `button` it still behave the same. Thing I discovered if I move the the whole *button* code to return statement *(outside the ExampleCustomInput)* it works perfectly. So I guess its the "passing of component" thing that caused this.

Comment: @FredStark my goal here is I can change the date value using datepicker, at the same time I can change also the value by changing directly to the input. Is that possible sir?

Comment: From the examples on `react-datepicker`'s site it looks like you can already do that by default without a custom component

Comment: Is there something you want to do that the default usage doesn't allow?

Comment: Can't that be solved with a little css? Can you edit the question to explain the final output you want? At the moment, the title doesn't reflect the question at all and the question doesn't include the required context. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @FredStark i just preparing the functionality. afterwards, I'll go with the design. Oth I updated the question title.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still unclear what requirement isn't met by the default DatePicker? it has both an editable input and a popup. Can you expand on why the default input doesn't work for your requirements?

Comment: @FredStark the default is working fine. But I need to create a custom design. But I don't know how to do it based in my expections/goal.